# pass value from jsp servlet to other jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have some problem to passing value from jsp #A to jsp #B. In jsp #A i will pass value using url, example below :

```
<label>Webpage URL :<a href='http://localhost:8080/hrms/applyvacan/index.htm?id=${vacancyForm.id}' target='new'> http://localhost:8080/hrms/applyvacan/index.htm</a>
```

for jsp #B :

```
<label>Vacancy Name</label>
<c:forEach items="${vacList}" var="vacancy" varStatus="loop">
<span> ${vacancy.vacname} </span>
</c:forEach>
```

i got the answer like this

> Vacancy for Business System Analyst Vacancy for Chairman Vacancy for CCO test

What i want is everytime i click on webpage url it will send only 1 id

Comment: It only sends 1 id, but in jsp #B instead of reading it, you are looping through all of them. In jsp B you can get id via ${param.id}

Comment: noted, i get it, let say in jsp #B i want to get name not id, it is possible to change from id to name in jsp #A and jsp #B.

Comment: It is possible, but not advisable. It is usually better to use id as it allows you to get item data from the database and name can be different for example, if you handle many languages. I don't know how your vacList and vacancy class look like, but you can always check id in the loop and display correct item or get only correct item instead of whole list from your backend.